# My c++ application doesn't write data on files correctly

Tags: c++, visual-c++, file-io, unicode, mfc

I am developing a C++ MFC application (Using visual studio 2010)

I have written this code for storing data on a file (code is inside of a button click event)

```
wfstream myfile;
myfile.open("ttt.txt");
if(!myfile)
    MessageBox(L"Problem");
else
{
    myfile <<"arash";
    myfile << ";program";
    myfile << ";test";
    myfile << ";a";
    MessageBox(L"OK");
myfile.close();

}
```

But output file is:

```
arash;program;test;aحححححححححح
```

And I have no idea where `حححححححححح` is came from ?!!!

I also tried

```
myfile << _T("arash");
myfile << _T(";program");
myfile << _T(";test");
myfile << _T(";a");
```

But It nothing changed

What ca I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide wide-character string to the file output, as it's a wide-character file:

```
myfile << L"arash";
myfile << L";program";
myfile << L";test";
myfile << L";a";
```

The reason the `_T` macro didn't work is perhaps that you haven't `_UNICODE` defined?

Comment: I have Same problem after doing this ... , nothing chaned

Comment: @Arashdn Is what you shown in your question all you've done with the file? Can you make e.g. an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @Arashdn And it's nothing to do with how you display the file? Which leads me to the natural follow up, **how** do you display the file contents?

Comment: I just created a new project and It's working well ... I really don't know what is wrong with current project

Answer (score 0):

In addition to providing wide-character literals with `L"something"`, which you must do since that's a wide-character stream, it is possible that the file already contains junk data from previous operations.

It sounds like you want to truncate the file (deleting all existing data) before writing to it. You can do that with

```
myfile.open("ttt.txt", ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ios_base::trunc);
```

Comment: Every time before testing app , I delete ttt.txt , I also tried your code but nothing changed ....

Comment: Is your project a UNICODE or a ANSI project ? Can you post the complete project that reproduces this probleb in a zip file ? I could not reproduce your problem with an ANSI build (I didn't try UNICODE), everything works fine for me.